# Built-in singles-to-pairs ({a, b, c, d} -> {{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, d}})?

Tags: list-manipulation

How to transform the list `{1,2,3,4}` into `{{1,2},{2,3},{3,4}}` i.e. the sequential or successive pairing of its elements starting from the first?

Currently I am using the following:

```
Transpose@{Drop[#, -1], Drop[#, 1]}& @Range@4
(*{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}*)
```

Comment: Yes it does, `Partition[Range[5], 2, 1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as mentioned by C.E. the preferred built-in function is:

```
Partition[Range[5], 2, 1]

(* {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}} *)
```

as pointed out by Simon Woods:

```
SequenceCases[Range[5], {_, _}, Overlaps -> True]
(* {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}} *)
```

one can also use `ReplaceList`

```
ReplaceList[Range[5], {___, a_, b_, ___} :> {a, b}]
(* {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}} *)
```

and like your user defined way one can also do it using `ReplaceAll` in a recursive manner

```
func[{x_Integer}] := {};
func[x_] := x /. {a_, q_, r___} :> Join[{{a, q}}, func[{q, r}]]

func[Range@5]
(* {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}} *)
```

another way

```
Thread[{Most@#,Rest@#}]&@Range[5]
(* {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}} *)
```

Comment: You could also use `SequenceCases[Range[5], {_, _}, Overlaps -> True]`

Comment: @SimonWoods thanks for pointing it out. incorporating your solution.